# Is there a bounded operator $A\in B(l^1(\mathbb{Z}))$, such that $e^A = S$, where $S$ is a shift operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is there a bounded operator $A\in B(l^1(\mathbb{Z}))$, such that $e^A = S$, where
$S$ is right shift operator?

For $a = (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \in l^1$, we have
$$Sa =(a_{n-1})_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} $$

and $e^A$ is defined as
$$e^A: = \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}$$

My attempts:

Proof by contradiction. Assume there is such an $A$. Then we can embed $S$ into [C0-semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup) i.e. we can define
$$S(t):= e^{At}$$
This is a family of continuous linear operators, which satisfy

$$S(t+s)  = S(t)S(s)$$

Moreover for a natural number $n$, $S(n)$ is a $n$-shift operator, which is an isometry.
This means that for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\|S(t)\| =\|S(\lfloor t \rfloor) + S(t-\lfloor t \rfloor)  \| \leq 1\cdot e^{\|A\|}$$

Also $A$ and $S$ commute i.e. $AS = SA$.

I haven't had much luck beyond that.

Comment: The operator $S$ is non-invertible, unlike $e^A.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc
It is invertible, the inverse is left shift operator. It wouldn't be invertible on $l^1(\mathbb{N})$, but we're on $l^1(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can identify $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ with the space $AF$ of functions, whose Fourier series are absolutely convergent
$$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{int}, \qquad -\pi\le t\le \pi$$
The operator $S$ corresponds to the  multiplication operator $Uf=e^{it}f$ for   $f\in AF.$
The assumption $e^A=S$ is equivalent to $e^C=U$ for an operator  $C\in B(AF).$
Hence $U=V^2,$ where $V=e^{C/2}.$ We have $UV=V^3=VU.$ Denote $g=V(1).$ Then
$$V(e^{int})=VU^n(1)=U^nV(1)=e^{int }g(t)$$
Thus
$$V\left (\sum a_ne^{int}\right )=g(t)\sum a_ne^{int}$$
Hence $V(f)=gf,$ for $f\in AF.$ Therefore $$e^{it}f(t)=(Uf)(t)=(V^2)(f)(t) =g(t)^2f(t)$$
This implies $g(t)^2=e^{it},$ where $g\in AF.$ We get  a contradiction, as $g(t)$ is a continuous periodic function with period $2\pi.$

Comment: Why is it a contradiction? Why can't $g(t)$ be equal to something like $e^{i\frac{t}{2}}$?
Because $Vf = gf$ is well-defined and I don't see why $V$ can't be of the form $e^{C/2}$.

Comment: There is no continuous function $g(t)$ with period $2\pi$ such that $g(t)^2=e^{it}.$

Comment: So this is in fact a stronger result. There's no bounded operator $V$, such that $V^2 = U$.